# How can you find out who the administrator of a SharePoint site is?

Tags: permissions, user-accounts, administrator, sharepoint

I do not have any rights besides Read for this SharePoint site. Is there a way to find out who the administrator for it is so I can let them know a user needs access?

Comment: Wouldn't you have a IT dept. to call or contact reguarding site access?

Comment: Ask IT dept is a good workaround for most users. However Not all deployments have a formal IT department (perhaps including OP?). I have scenario where I request access repeatedly but admins never reply (reject or accept). I can't easily track down the Site administrator(s) and don't want to involve my multi-national Enterprise IT department.:-).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The user that doesn't have access should browse to the site where the Access Denied error appears. On this page they can click a link requesting access and fill in a text box where they can explain why. Once submitted this message will go to the SharePoint administrator.

See [this article on Office Online](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepointserver/HA102388501033.aspx) for more info and screenshots.

Comment: This is helpful answer for requesting access but doesn't answer OP question regarding who the SharePoint Site admin is. Not all deployments have a formal IT department.